# find a word containing symbols using php

Tags: php

I am currently developing a simple chat script..

in that i need to use `@mensions` -- Like (Facebook,Twitter) eg `@user2019`

i need a php to separate to find the `@mensions`  and remove that from the text

Eg : user types like this  `" @user2019 hi this is a text message"`

i need to search and replace `@user2019` with a space and i need to get the username

how its possible using php ?

I tried using the below script

```
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$domain = strstr($email, '@');

echo $domain."<br/>"; // prints @example.com

$user = strstr($email, '@', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
echo $user."<br/>"; // prints name
```

Comment: "*i need to search and replace @user2019 with a space and i need to get the username*" — Could you clarify? What is the final result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @AmalMurali i need to separate the string and save it in a seperate variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a regexp to capture the username, and then to remove the username from the message :

```
$string = "blabla @user2019 hi this is a text message";
$pattern = '/(.*?)@\w+(.*?)/i';
$replacement = '${1}';

$getuser = preg_match('/@\w+/', $string, $matches);
$username = str_replace('@', '', $matches[0]);
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Result :

> > blabla  hi this is a text message
> >
> > $username : user2019